# How to go from one JSP page to other by clicking submit button?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to jump from one JSP page to other JSP page by clicking submit button. How to do that in easy way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use `<form action="page2.jsp">`
- *or* submit to a servlet using `<form action="targetServlet">`, and then:

  - redirect to page2, using `response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp")`
  - *or* forward to page2, using `request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp").forward()`

Comment: what u have suggested is fine but is there any way of doing without using servlet....like any html tag or jsp tag

Comment: the first option is exactly such - you only use `<form>`